# How to synchronize runtime upload files in a web farm?

Tags: web-farm, web-farm-framework

We like to run our asp.net web application to a web farm.A lot of files will be uploaded to the server at run time.What will be the best approach to synchronize the runtime uploaded files on web farm?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. what do "managing uploaded files" mean to you? Show some code. Also, tag your question appropriately.

Comment: If we upload the image in our application running on webfarm,that will be upload in one server,we need to replicate the image to all the servers of the webfarm.How could we do this?